# Get tweet content from tweet id

Tags: php, twitter

How i retrieve a tweet content using tweet id? is it possible using twitter API?
am using PHP

Help is highly appreciable.

Comment: You have to try something first.

Comment: https://dev.twitter.com/

Comment: yes see:: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/show/%3Aid

Comment: You really should have tried google. "retrieve tweet by id" gives you the solution in the second result.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [statuses/show/:id](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/show/%3aid)

```
json_decode(file_get_contents('http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/show/308910231910490112.json'));
```

*note: file_get_contents required [`allow_url_fopen`](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php).*

although version 1 of the twitter API is deprecated, so in version [1.1](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/show/%3aid) you will need to authenticate using a Twitter application. See [here](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/8045) on how to create an Twitter application.

Answer (score 0):

You use Twitter API to do that.

See here to learn how to fetch message using twit ID:

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/show/%3Aid

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you?

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/show/%3Aid

They have really rich [documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/platform-objects/tweets) with examples.